# Inserting data in to sqllite with flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Faced an issue, while creating and inserting data (date and time)into a sqllite table .Like whenever the user clicks a button i want it to get added to the database and get displayed in the homepage.I am getting the below error.Please help`

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sql.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

final String tableName = "todo";
final String Column_id = "id";
final String Column_Month = "month";

class TaskModel {
final String month;
int id;

TaskModel({this.month, this.id});
Map<String, dynamic> tomap() {
return {Column_Month: this.month};
}
}

class TodoHelper {
Database db;

TodoHelper() {
initDatabase();
}

Future<void> initDatabase() async {
db = await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), "my_database.db"),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
  return db.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $tableName($Column_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,$Column_Month TEXT)");
}, version: 1);
}

Future<void> insertTask(TaskModel task) async {
try {
  db.insert(tableName, task.tomap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
} catch (_) {
  print(_);
}
}

Future<List<TaskModel>> getAllTask() async {
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks = await db.query(tableName);

List.generate(tasks.length, (index) {
  TaskModel(month: tasks[index][Column_Month], id: tasks[index][Column_id]);
});
}
 }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
E/flutter (11503): Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
E/flutter (11503):  (no such table: todo (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM todo)
E/flutter (11503): #################################################################) sql 'SELECT * FROM todo' args []} ".  This is the error code I got

Comment: @Dhanush Please [edit] the error message into your code – it's much easier to read there (and comments may disappear). Have you checked if the table `todo` is actually there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Future initDatabase() async {
    db = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'my_database.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        db.execute('''
          create table $tableName(
            $Column_id integer primary key autoincrement,
            $Column_Month text,
             )
        ''');
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Actually it is the same error coming up .I dont think the table is created .

Comment: i have the same problem, i dont know how to add values in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Check this Url "https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite" . you will find a good example for sqlite in flutter